# How can I use pdf.js to display the first page of every user-uploaded pdf file as a preview in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, pdf.js

Up to now i have successfully display the first page preview for one pdf file but it doesn't work for remaining others.

**models.py**

```
import uuid
from django.db import models


class PdfUploader(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pdf_uploader'
        ordering = ['-uploaded_at']

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.docfile.name.split("/")[4].replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ')
```

**views.py**

```
class PdfUploadView(CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'form': PdfUploadForm()}
        return render(request, 'partials/pdf_upload_form.htm', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PdfUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('docfile')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                file_instance = PdfUploader(docfile=f)
                file_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('pdf-list'))
        return render(request, 'partials/pdf_upload_form.htm', {'form': form})
```

**pdf_upload_form.htm**

```
{% block "content" %}
<div role="main" class="main">
    <section class="section section-default pt-5 m-0">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**pdf_lists.htm**
By following official [official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script), I am passing a context variable as JSON to the pdf.js.

```
{% for obj in pdfs %}
    <tr>
         <td>
              {{ forloop.counter }}
         </td>
         <td>
             <a href="{{ obj.docfile.url }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{obj.filename}}</a>
         </td>
         <td>
              {{ obj.uploaded_at|date:"d-M-Y" }}
         </td>
         <td>
             <a href="{{obj.docfile.url}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                 <canvas id="the-canvas" style="height:250px;">
                 </canvas>
                 {{obj.docfile.url|json_script:'mydata'}}
             </a>
         </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**pdf.js**
Now I'm reading the previously passed JSON, which contains the path to the user's submitted pdf file to further process it using JS to display the first page of pdf as preview.

```
const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);
console.log(mydata);

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF

var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(mydata);
loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
    console.log('PDF loaded');

    // Fetch the first page
    var pageNumber = 1;
    pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        console.log('Page loaded');

        var scale = 0.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            console.log('Page rendered');
        });
    });
}, function (reason) {
    // PDF loading error
    console.error(reason);
});
```

screenshot of the result:
As you can see, the first pdf file displays a preview, while the rest do not.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by creating specific canvas for each PDF file.
Please replace the PDF file with your server files.

Here is the **js code**

```
function LoadAndPrint()
{
    var files = [{name:'sample1.pdf',url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf'},{name:'sample2.pdf',url:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf'}];

    var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

    files.forEach(myFunc);
    function myFunc(file,i){

        idContainer.innerHTML += 
        '<span>'+file.name+'</span><canvas id="the-canvas'+i+'"></canvas><hr><br>';

        var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(file.url);
        loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
            console.log('PDF loaded');

            var pageNumber = 1;
            pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
            console.log('Page loaded');

                var scale = 1.1;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

                var canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas"+i);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                  canvasContext: context,
                  viewport: viewport
                };

                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                  console.log('Page rendered');
                });
            });
        }, function (reason) {
          console.error(reason);
        });
    }
}
```

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="idPrint" onclick="LoadAndPrint()">Load and Print</button><br>
        <div id="idContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And here is the** [JSFiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/raju10281/s0dfgnw8/2/)

Comment: Just a note: with current pdf.js version this line throws an error:
`pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';`

I had to comment it in order to make the script work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only call your script 1 time. Its input is 1 object with id 'mydata' and one canvas with id 'the-canvas' that serves as output.

What you should do:

First, assign a unique ID to each **data** and to each **canvas** element.

For canvas it is simple:

```
  <canvas id="the-canvas{{ forloop.counter }}" style="height:250px;">
  </canvas>
```

For data it is a little more complex due to json_script filter, something like this:

```
{% with mydata_id="mydata"|add:forloop.counter %}
    {{obj.docfile.url|json_script:mydata_id}}
{% endwith %}
```

Then you also have to know the length of `pdfs`, so maybe add something like this after the for loop, quick and dirty:

```
<script> const mypdfslength = {{ pdfs | length }}; </script>
```

Just make sure to place this before your JS.

Next, in your js, you have to put all your code inside a for loop from 0 to `mypdfslength`.

And, of course, when resolving `mydata` and `canvas`, make sure to reference them by their new ID, which would be, considering `i` is your for loop index:

```
const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById(`mydata{i}`).textContent);
```

and

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(`the-canvas{i}`);
```

That's it.

Disclaimer: I didn't really test it, but that is definitely the direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into the issue. I followed the instructions outlined above. But now it's throwing this error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

Comment: As I mentioned it is a direction to solve your problem, not a recipe. So it cannot find the element `mydata0` or whatever number. I suggest you debug it by looking at the html source of the page you got. What ids do you see on your data script clauses? Are they correctly generated, is their format `mydataNUMBER` ?

Comment: I checked my html source code and everything is in the right sequence. And the above error has been resolved in some way. The error message is now "Cannot use the same canvas during multiple render operations." p.s. I'm not familiar with javascript.